# How do I determine for each order whether it is over or under the average order value in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, r, window-functions

My Table looks like this

```
CUST   Date       Value
102  2019-12-03   7
101  2019-12-06   8
102  2019-12-06   7
102  2019-12-13   10
102  2019-12-17   5
102  2019-12-18   5
103  2019-12-22   5
102  2019-12-22   7
```

Comment: Sample data is great. Show us the expected result too.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or R? Or both?

Comment: Show desired output for this data. Add explanations.

Comment: Well i get stuck with SQL after this

select *, avg(value) over(partition by cust) as avg_score
  from sales

Comment: @jarlh I need to present it with SQL and R

Comment: Your query implies over of under avg by customer but the title implies over the entire table  Or you might mean the avg by cutomer compared to avg for all other customers which do you want?

Comment: @P.Salmon yeah i have actually no clue on how i can present this :(

Comment: @jnm at this stage it's about deciding what average means - you have told us how you want the data presented//

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do this using R with `dplyr` library.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  group_by(CUST) %>%
  mutate(Label = ifelse(Value > mean(Value, na.rm = TRUE), 
                        'over average', 'under average'))

#    CUST  Date       Value Label        
#  <int> <chr>      <int> <chr>        
#1   102 2019-12-03     7 over average 
#2   101 2019-12-06     8 under average
#3   102 2019-12-06     7 over average 
#4   102 2019-12-13    10 over average 
#5   102 2019-12-17     5 under average
#6   102 2019-12-18     5 under average
#7   103 2019-12-22     5 under average
#8   102 2019-12-22     7 over average
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(CUST = c(102L, 101L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 102L, 103L, 
102L), Date = c("2019-12-03", "2019-12-06", "2019-12-06", "2019-12-13", 
"2019-12-17", "2019-12-18", "2019-12-22", "2019-12-22"), Value = c(7L, 
8L, 7L, 10L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 7L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Comment: I wonder what the average is.

Comment: Ahh this is it thanks!! just need the one in SQL

Answer (score 0):

Hope this example can help you to demonstrate your problem, (presented in MySQL 8.0):

```
select *, avg(value) over(partition by cust) as avg_score from sales
```

**[RESULT]:**

[image]

Will be:

[image]

**[EDIT]:**
Live Demo

> ```
> create table sales (CUST int,   Date1 date, Value int);
>
> INSERT INTO sales  VALUES (102,"2019-12-03",7);
> INSERT INTO sales  VALUES (101,"2019-12-06",8);
> INSERT INTO sales  VALUES (102,"2019-12-06",7);
> INSERT INTO sales  VALUES (102,"2019-12-13",10);
> INSERT INTO sales  VALUES (102,"2019-12-17",5);
> INSERT INTO sales  VALUES (102,"2019-12-18",5);
> INSERT INTO sales  VALUES (103,"2019-12-22",5);
> INSERT INTO sales  VALUES (102,"2019-12-22",7);
> ```

> ```
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
>
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select *
> from sales;
> ```
>
> ```
> CUST | Date1      | Value
> ---: | :--------- | ----:
>  102 | 2019-12-03 |     7
>  101 | 2019-12-06 |     8
>  102 | 2019-12-06 |     7
>  102 | 2019-12-13 |    10
>  102 | 2019-12-17 |     5
>  102 | 2019-12-18 |     5
>  103 | 2019-12-22 |     5
>  102 | 2019-12-22 |     7
> ```

> ```
> select *, avg(value) over(partition by cust) as avg_score from sales
> ```

> ```
> CUST | Date1      | Value | avg_score
> ---: | :--------- | ----: | --------:
>  101 | 2019-12-06 |     8 |    8.0000
>  102 | 2019-12-03 |     7 |    6.8333
>  102 | 2019-12-06 |     7 |    6.8333
>  102 | 2019-12-13 |    10 |    6.8333
>  102 | 2019-12-17 |     5 |    6.8333
>  102 | 2019-12-18 |     5 |    6.8333
>  102 | 2019-12-22 |     7 |    6.8333
>  103 | 2019-12-22 |     5 |    5.0000
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=23290bbad6d1fb98c735244cf8ed9fd9)*

Comment: This only shows me the avg,  it need to tell me if the value is below or above of the total avg of the value